# how to subtract a value from a field in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am have a table Reseller and Users. Now Each user is mapped by his Reseller with a field called **KEY** which uniquely defines the reseller! now I have a form where i edit a user. in here if reseller sets the balance of user to yes then i want to subtract 5 euros from the balance field of Reseller. Below is my code:

the controller to check if reseller has set balance to yes:

```
 if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes")
         {
            $this->reseller_m->deduct();
         }
```

**the Mode function which should subtract 5 from reseller balance:**

```
public function deduct($balance)
{
    $this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5');
    $this->db->where('id' , $id);
    $this->db->update('reseller',$data);
}
```

the edit code :

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
{

     $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
    if($usertype ==="reseller")
    {

    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id','sip_pass','name','email', 'password','phone','status','created','balance'));
        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);



        $this->user_m->save($data, $id);


         if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes")
         {

            $this->reseller_m->deduct();

            //echo "goimng";
         }


        redirect('reseller/user');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/edit';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $this->data);


}
else{
    $this->load->view('permission');
}

}
```

help me to subtract 5 from reseller only when he edits his own user and should not affect others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in  your model, where `$id` is the id of the reseller.

```
public function deduct($id)
{
    $this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5', false);
    $this->db->where('id' , $id);
    $this->db->update('reseller');
}
```

Also, in your controller you must know the reseller's id, and use it when you call the model function:

```
 if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes")
 {
    $this->reseller_m->deduct($id); //you must have the $id (reseller's id) value set
 }
```

Comment: should i not be passing the key instead of id ?

Comment: hey this is right for reseller module. But i also have a admin user he can edit Reseller and User As well. now if he edits a users and sets the balance to yes how will the balance deducted? because each user is mapped with reseller by a field called KEY which is uniuqe

Comment: Hey, it looks like you already have an answer to your question. If you have another question, go to to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Yeah okay :) but can you please tell me why you used where id, $id ?

Comment: I'm sure Saty can answer that too, but here you go: $id is the index of the user in the table 'reseller'. So the query means 'Adjust the column balance for the reseller where the id is $id'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88579/discussion-between-rajan-and-webcrazymaniac).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353451/how-do-i-write-a-trigger-that-resets-the-value-of-a-field-after-30-days i have added a new question please check

Answer (score 2):

[set()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.

Use `FALSE` as third parameter in your set

```
$this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5',FALSE);
```

Also you are not define `$id and $data` in your function and change your update to

```
$this->db->update('reseller');
```

So finally your function would be

**MODEL**

```
 public function deduct($id)
    {
        $this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5',FALSE);
        $this->db->where('id' , $id);
        $this->db->update('reseller');
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
if($this->input->post('balance') === "Yes")
         {

            $this->reseller_m->deduct($id);/// pass youe id here

            //echo "goimng";
         }
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but it did not affect the balance field ! any idea where i am wrong

Comment: Why OP should use your code. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Because you are not define `$id` and `$data` in your function

Comment: ALso remove $data fron update it would be `$this->db->update('reseller');`

Comment: Yes was thinking that could be the issue but i removed all the line from deduct function i just kept the $this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5',FALSE);

Comment: @Rajan Ahh have you cheeked my model and controller code??

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i think i have elaborate more then enough!! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88578/discussion-between-rajan-and-saty).

Comment: @Saty could you please help me once again?

Comment: Hi if i pass an id it does'nt works its says undefied variable id

Comment: @Saty I have a field called Key that identifies which users belong to which reseller! so i think i should be passing $key in function right? i tried both id and key but didnt work for me  :(  it only works it i dont pass anything but that updates all the reseller so i should pass something

Answer (score 1):

Try
    `$this->db->set('balance', 'balance-5', FALSE);`

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but it did not affect the balance field ! any idea where i am wrong

Comment: Why OP should use your code. Can you please elaborate

Comment: See Reseller logs in to his account. then He can view his balance and view and edit his users. Now if he edits a user and sets the balance to yes i want to deduct 5 euros everytime he sets it to yes

Comment: What is within `$data` within `$this->db->update('reseller',$data);` `<------` @Rajan

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i have updated the question code $data is contains all the post fields

Answer (score 0):

To make the Value Dynamic I am using this like to Product Stock Update

Here, The `$purchase_qty` is ordered Item. `$product_id` is the ordered product.

```
$this->db->set("stock", "stock - $purchase_qty", FALSE)
        ->where('price_id', $price_id)
        ->where('product_id', $product_id)
        ->update('price_table');
```

> Hope this will help you.